# Select one column data in different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to match two tables, table1 and table2, for one row of table1 I have two or more rows in table 2 and I want to display them in one row.

Now I have the following:

```
Select
    a.[ID], b.[Description]
From 
    table1 a, table2 b 
Where 
    a.[ID] = b.[ID];
```

Output:

```
[ID] | [Description]
-----+--------------
1    | Fee
1    | Domestic Fee
2    | Fee
2    | International Fee
```

I want to get the following result

```
[ID] | [Description1] | [Description2]
-----+----------------+---------------
1    | Fee            | Domestic Fee
2    | Fee            | International Fee
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Search for PIVOT. What if there will be more than 2 descriptions?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I searched for PIVOT but it needs some aggregate functions, which I don't need. There will be fixed amount of descriptions per on row for table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple descriptions then you can use Pivot as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select *, RowN = Concat('Description', Row_Number() over (partition by Id order by Id)) from #description ) a
    pivot (max([Description]) for RowN in ([Description1],[Description2])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------+
| Id | Description1 |   Description2    |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
|  1 | Fee          | Domestic Fee      |
|  2 | Fee          | International Fee |
+----+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You have to make that dynamic sql.  What will happen if there's a third Description -- it's not specified in your 'for' clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is my proposal with cross apply operator

data prepartaion:

```
create table tst_1 (id int, dsc nvarchar(30))

insert into tst_1 (id, dsc)
values (1,'Fee'),(1,'Domestic Fee'),(2,'Fee'),(2,'International Fee')
```

Next simple select with jon show data that you looking for:

```
select t1.id, t1.dsc, x.dsc
from tst_1 t1
cross apply ( select row_number() over (order by id) as lp
                                        ,id
                                        ,dsc
                            from tst_1 )x
where x.id = t1.id and x.dsc <> t1.dsc
and lp%2 = 0
```

`tst_1` can be a view based on `select ...` from you question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
    a.[ID],a.[Description], b.[Description]
From 
    table1 a left outer join table2 b 
on
    a.[ID] = b.[ID];``
```

Comment: why LEFT OUTER JOIN and not INNER JOIN ?

Comment: Is there a [description] field in Table 1?  I think you're making assumptions.

Comment: @greespark just an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select ID, DESCRIPTION1, DESCRIPTION2
from
(
    Select a.[ID]
      ,b.[Description]
      ,'DESCRIPTION' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY a.ID) AS VARCHAR(255))AS RN
  from table1 a 
  JOIN  table2 b ON  a.[ID] = b.[ID] 
) d
pivot
(
  max([Description])
  for RN in (DESCRIPTION1,DESCRIPTION2)
) piv;
```